# Input field saves differently at controller side (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, validation, directive

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bljtDjcU5qNFolCQuehU?p=preview).
As user types in input, commas gets added on the fly. That's the purpose of using a directive. It also shows 2 decimal places.

My problem is-
for e.g. if i type in '2300.34' in the input field and click 'Submit', it will give me a string of 230034 at the controller side. I have used console.log to check the data i am getting at the controller side. I want the data to be as it is at the controller. how can i achieve this ?

JS and directive

```
var app = angular.module('App',[]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

                        $scope.getdata = function(){
                            console.log($scope.amount);
                        }

});



app.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',

    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) return;


        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue);
        });


        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+]/g, '');
            elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber/100,2));
            return plainNumber;
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

HTML part

```
<body ng-app="App">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="amount" format="number" />
  <input type="submit" ng-click="getdata()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use JavaScript's built-in `parseFloat` and `toFixed` methods inside your `$parsers.unshift` function :

```
var plainNumber = parseFloat(viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+]/g, '')).toFixed(2);
```

Also,

```
return plainNumber/100.00
```

Comment: 2300.34 is now saving as 230034.00 if i use your line of code

Comment: @Ayesha Updated the answer